# Devops Timeline Estimates

Tags: estimation, timeline, devops

Im having trouble finding sources as to how much time should be allocated for devops tasks that include dockerizing the code, creating ci/cd pipeline (on AWS for example), as well as creating the terraform script to deploy a solution?

Comment: Welcome to PMSE!

Comment: Why would you think there's a standard answer for this? Ask yourself "How long does it take to run one mile?" and you'll see a large range based on factors like age, health, environmental conditions, whether you're running uphill or downhill, *et cetera ad nauseum.*

Comment: The only valid source of data is from the team that will be doing the work. It doesn't matter how long it would take anyone else.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs I was asked to create a timeline that could be presented to the client, and we don't have a devops (one will be hired for the project). I just need to put a timeframe that would be reasonable, and personally I don't have much experience in these tasks as I'm a developer. And it is important for me not to underestimate the devops tasks as they will affect QA and milestone presentations for the client.

Comment: DevOps is a philosophy and a broad skill set, not a role or person. If you treat DevOps as a singular person, you will not be implementing DevOps properly. If you're being asked to estimate something that can't be estimated, then don't. Hire a DevOps consultant to look over your project plan and provide an estimate. Even if it's off by an order of magnitude, it will still be more accurate than an inexpert guess or using irrelevant data from entirely different projects as guesstimates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All depends on how mature are your devops infrastructure and practices. As always with estimates the best answer is to ask the team who will be doing the work, but typically I would not expect the things you mentioned to be estimated separately at all. They are probably better considered as part of the Definition of Done that influences estimates of other backlog items. Perhaps it's also worth mentioning that many teams prefer to estimate in points rather than time.

Answer (score 2):

As [nvogel already answered](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/34930/4384) you have to talk to the teams doing the work.

You mentioned 3 very different types of tasks:

1. *Dockerizing the code*, is a one-off task that you probably want your engineers involved in so that the code remains dockerized.
2. *Creating ci/cd pipeline (on AWS for example)* is a classic DevOps task and involves creating an entire mini-infrastructure as well as putting best practices in place. You need rules as to who can deploy to where (e.g. test servers, staging, live) and how to deal with failed builds (who owns the crash, how soon it must be fixed, etc.).
3. *Creating the terraform script to deploy a solution* is theoretically a one-time ProdOps task. In practice, it needs to be continuously updated as the system matures and grows.

These tasks can take between weeks and months depending on your team, their experience, the tools being used, and the complexity of the system.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on too many factors to give you a simple answer, some of them would be:

- Complexity of the application you have
- Complexity of the infrastructure you need
- Current infrastructure that can be reused
- Templates you already have established in the company/project, that can be reused
- Security requirements you need to be compliant with
- How complete and set are the requirements (if all factors are known and how likely are they to change in the meantime)
- Experience of the DevOps Engineer
- Efficiency of the cooperation in the team (with devs, QAs, security team)

It can vary, based on my own experience, from about half a day for a very simple project I could set you from scratch with no resources to reuse and no requirements regarding HA, reliability, etc., to like a month for an app having more than one service, needing to be highly reliable, scalable, requiring complex pipeline to build the docker image, requiring many dependencies to be incorporated into the docker image, be optimized for building time, with encrypted S3, encrypted database, using more than one database, etc.

If there's a project similar to one you already had within the same organization/project, you can make some assumptions based on that.
If not, the engineer performing that should give you some rough estimate and for worst case scenario I would double the estimated time.

I was participating in projects that were similar, where they were initially taking 2-3 weeks for an experienced DevOps Engineer and were cut to 2-3 days for less experienced one, but from project to project the templates base was improved, tuned and having more parts available and ready to reuse - but producing all that stuff has taken like 3 years of constant improving by a dozen of engineers and final solution mostly required setting parameters, rarely and additional changers for the common cases.